# How to copy all database users from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am making a database from a backup file (I'll call this db 1) and I need to duplicate the users of one database (and this db 2) to the newly restored database.

The first step I know must be done is to delete all the existing users in the newly restored database.

What is the proper way to then copy the users from db 2 to db 1?

Comment: You might have better luck over on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - in the meantime: are the two databases on the same SQL server?  (that makes it easier) .... (hint: SELECT .... FROM sys.sysusers)

Comment: Yes they are on the same server.  I was going to do an insert select from sys.sysusers but I wasn't sure if there would be any unwanted side effects from doing that.  Are there any foreseeable side effects from doing so?  Also do I need to update sys.database_principals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just use an INSERT .... SELECT construct.

You need to use the sys.users info to generate CREATE USER statements and execute those statements.

If this is a one time thing, I would use

```
select 'CREATE USER [' + uu.name + '] FOR LOGIN ' + ll.name + ' ;'
from sys.sysusers uu
    join master.sys.syslogins ll on ll.sid = uu.sid
```

then capture the output, paste the output into a batch and run that batch - quick and easy for a one-off.

If you need to do this in an automated fashion, you can use a cursor:

```
USE DB2 -- the source of the users
DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
  select 'CREATE USER [' + uu.name + '] FOR LOGIN ' + ll.name + ' ;'
from sys.sysusers uu
    join master.sys.syslogins ll on ll.sid = uu.sid 

DECLARE @cmdString varchar(max) --for storing the first half of INSERT statement
OPEN cursCol
USE DB1 -- the target of the created users
FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @cmdString;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
   PRINT @cmdString;
   EXEC (@cmdString);

   FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @cmdString;
END
CLOSE cursCol
DEALLOCATE cursCol
```

If it wasn't the same server, you'd have more script to generate, but it can still be done.

Comment: Do you need the part to deal with existing users?

Comment: just added a couple of lines to clarify the source/target db part - could also fully qualify the FROM clause: `db2.sys.sysusers`

Comment: I don't have existing users.  Now I only have to deal with deleting the orphaned users resulting from the restore.

Comment: You mean, something like this: `SELECT 'DROP  USER [' + uu.name + ']   ;'
from sys.sysusers uu     LEFT OUTER join master.sys.syslogins ll on ll.sid = uu.sid  WHERE ll.sid is null;`